# Find function only works in the first workbook

Tags: excel, vba, find

I'm using the Find function to relate a main workbook with many others, it is supossed to find a parameter and change its value. The problem is that it only works in the first workbook, it can't find the parameter in the others

parameter(j) is storing the value correctly and the all the workbooks and worksheets are open correctly, what could be wrong?

```vb
    Global proximo As Boolean
    Sub atualizar()

dados_alterados.Hide

                               

Dim parametro(100) As Variant, especificacao(100) As Variant, unidade(100) As Variant, metodo(100) As Variant
Dim referencia(100) As Variant, limite_legal(100) As Variant, parametro_novo(100) As Variant
Dim celula_inicial As Variant, celula_final As Variant
Dim inicio As Integer, final As Integer


'Finds where the updated information is

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Worksheets("PLANILHA REFERÊNCIA").Activate

Set celula_inicial = Cells.Find(What:="DADOS FÍSICO-QUÍMICOS", _
                                  After:=Cells(1, 1), _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                                
inicio = CInt(Split(celula_inicial.Address, "$")(2))

   '                               SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _



Set celula_final = Cells.Find(What:="REFERÊNCIAS", _
                                  After:=Cells(1, 1), _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlWhole, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 MatchCase:=False)
                                

final = CInt(Split(celula_final.Address, "$")(2))

'Stores the updated parameters (just one column)

   For i = 3 To final - 1 
    
        Set parametro(i) = Cells(inicio + i, 1)
        
    If dados_alterados.OptionButton1 = True Then
        Set especificacao(i) = Cells(inicio + i, 2)
    End If
    If dados_alterados.OptionButton2 = True Then
        Set unidade(i) = Cells(inicio + i, 3)
    End If
    If dados_alterados.OptionButton3 = True Then
        Set metodo(i) = Cells(inicio + i, 4)
    End If
    If dados_alterados.OptionButton4 = True Then
        Set referencia(i) = Cells(inicio + i, 5)
    End If
    If dados_alterados.OptionButton5 = True Then
        Set limite_legal(i) = Cells(inicio + i, 6)
    End If
       
    Next i
    
    


Dim arquivo(200) As String, planilha(200) As String
Dim n_ETPA As Integer, n_ETPI_conv As Integer, n_ETPI_org As Integer
Dim contador1 As Integer, contador2 As Integer, n_planilhas As Integer



caminho = atualizacao.TextBox1
' these are the files 

planilha(1) = "\ETPA 001.xlsx"
planilha(2) = "\ETPA 002.xlsx"
planilha(3) = "\ETPA 003.xlsx"
planilha(4) = "\ETPA 004.xlsx"
planilha(5) = "\ETPA 005.xlsx"
planilha(6) = "\ETPA 006.xlsx"
planilha(7) = "\ETPA 007.xlsx"
planilha(8) = "\ETPA 008.xlsx"
planilha(9) = "\ETPA 009.xlsx"
planilha(10) = "\ETPA 010 .xlsx"
planilha(11) = "\ETPA 011.xlsx"
planilha(12) = "\ETPA 012.xlsx"
planilha(13) = "\ETPA 013.xlsx"
planilha(14) = "\ETPA 014.xlsx"
planilha(15) = "\ETPA 015.xlsx"
planilha(16) = "\ETPA 016.xlsx"
planilha(17) = "\ETPA 017.xlsx"
planilha(18) = "\ETPA 018.xlsx"
planilha(19) = "\ETPA 019.xlsx"

planilha(20) = "\ETPA 020.xlsx"
planilha(21) = "\ETPA 021.xlsx"
planilha(22) = "\ETPA 022.xlsx"
planilha(23) = "\ETPA 023.xlsx"

       
        planilha(24) = "\ETPA 024.xlsx"
        planilha(25) = "\ETPA 025.xlsx"

'orgânicos
planilha(26) = "\ETPA 026.xlsx"
planilha(27) = "\ETPA 027.xlsx"
planilha(28) = "\ETPA 028.xlsx"
planilha(29) = "\ETPA 029.xlsx"

planilha(30) = "\ETPA 030.xlsx"
planilha(31) = "\ETPA 031.xlsx"
planilha(32) = "\ETPA 032.xlsx"

    
        planilha(33) = "\ETPA 033.xlsx"
        planilha(34) = "\ETPA 034.xlsx"

planilha(35) = "\ETPA 035.xlsx"
planilha(36) = "\ETPA 036.xlsx"
planilha(37) = "\ETPA 037.xlsx"
planilha(38) = "\ETPA 038.xlsx"
planilha(39) = "\ETPA 039.xlsx"

planilha(40) = "\ETPA 040.xlsx"
planilha(41) = "\ETPA 041.xlsx"
planilha(42) = "\ETPA 042.xlsx"
planilha(43) = "\ETPA 043.xlsx"
planilha(44) = "\ETPA 043.xlsx"
'ORGÂNICOS
        'FARELO
        planilha(45) = "\ETPA 044.xlsx"
        planilha(46) = "\ETPA 046.xlsx"

planilha(47) = "\ETPA 047.xlsx"
planilha(48) = "\ETPA 048.xlsx"
planilha(49) = "\ETPA 049.xlsx"
planilha(50) = "\ETPA 050.xlsx"
n_ETPA = 50


planilha(n_ETPA + 1) = "\ETPI 01.xlsx"
planilha(n_ETPA + 2) = "\ETPI 02.xlsx"
planilha(n_ETPA + 3) = "\ETPI 03.xlsx"
planilha(n_ETPA + 4) = "\ETPI 04.xlsx"
'ETPI Orgânico:
planilha(n_ETPA + 5) = "\ETPI 08.xlsx"
planilha(n_ETPA + 6) = "\ETPI 09.xlsx"
planilha(n_ETPA + 7) = "\ETPI 10.xlsx"


n_ETPI_conv = 4
n_ETPI_org = 3

'
contador1 = CInt(atualizacao.TextBox9)
contador2 = CInt(atualizacao.TextBox10)


n_planilhas = n_ETPA + n_ETPI_conv + n_ETPI_org

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim nome_aba As String
Dim revisao_atual As Integer

'every k is a workbook
For k = contador1 To contador2
If k <= n_ETPA Then

If k = 26 Or k = 27 Or k = 28 Or k = 29 Or k = 30 Or k = 31 Or k = 32 Or k = 47 Or k = 48 Or k = 49 Or k = 50 Then 'orgânicos
Set caminho = atualizacao.TextBox2
Else
Set caminho = atualizacao.TextBox1
End If
End If


If n_ETPA < k And k <= (n_ETPA + n_ETPI_conv) Then
Set caminho = atualizacao.TextBox3
End If
If (n_ETPA + n_ETPI_conv) < k And k <= (n_ETPA + n_ETPI_conv + n_ETPI_org) Then
Set caminho = atualizacao.TextBox4
End If




If k = 24 Or k = 25 Or k = 33 Or k = 34 Or k = 45 Or k = 46 Then 'integral
Else
arquivo(k) = caminho + planilha(k)
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(arquivo(k))
If k <= n_ETPA Then
nome_aba = "1"
End If
If k > n_ETPA Then
nome_aba = "6"
End If




Worksheets(nome_aba).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False





revisao_atual = CInt(Cells(2, 18))




'MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name, vbInformation, "Workbook Name"


                                
Dim endereco(100) As String
Dim linha(100) As Integer

'here is where the parameter is found and the updated value is substituted
'the problem occurs when it updates the second workbook, it works perfectly 
'in the first workbook and doesn´t matter which workbook I set as first.
 For j = 3 To final - 1 'busca o nome da especificação e substitui o valor
 
            Set parametro_novo(j) = wb.Sheets(nome_aba).Cells.Find(What:=parametro(j), _
                                  After:=Cells(1, 1), _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                 MatchCase:=False)

            
        If Not parametro_novo(j) Is Nothing Then
                endereco(j) = parametro_novo(j).Address 'fornece a célula na qual o parâmetro foi encontrado
                coluna_letra = Split(endereco(j), "$")(1)
                
            If coluna_letra = "A" Then
                
                'coluna = Range(coluna & "1").Column
                linha(j) = Split(endereco(j), "$")(2)
                
                If dados_alterados.OptionButton1 = True Then
                    Cells(linha(j), 5) = especificacao(j)
                End If
                If dados_alterados.OptionButton2 = True Then
                    Cells(linha(j), 8) = unidade(j)
                End If
                If dados_alterados.OptionButton3 = True Then
                    Cells(linha(j), 10) = metodo(j)
                End If
                If dados_alterados.OptionButton4 = True Then
                    Cells(linha(j), 14) = referencia(j)
                End If
                If dados_alterados.OptionButton5 = True Then
                    Cells(linha(j), 18) = limite_legal(j)
                End If
                

                
            End If
        End If
              

                
                
 
             
       Set parametro_novo(j) = Nothing

Next j






End If

Dim ref As String, celula_ref As Variant, nova_ref As String
Dim linha_ref As Integer, nova_linha_ref As Integer


If proximo = False Then


ref = atualizacao.TextBox11
If ref <> "" Then

Set celula_ref = Cells.Find(What:="REFERÊNCIAS", _
                                  After:=Cells(1, 1), _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlWhole, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 MatchCase:=True)
linha_ref = CInt(Split(celula_ref.Address, "$")(2))

Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
m = 0
Set myRange = Range(Cells(linha_ref + 1, 1), Cells(linha_ref + 20, 1))
For Each myCell In myRange
        m = m + 1
    If IsEmpty(myCell) Then
prox_ref_linha = linha_ref + m
Exit For
    End If
Next myCell


Dim ultima_ref As String
Dim ultima_ref_num As Integer



ultima_ref = Cells(prox_ref_linha - 1, 1)
ultima_ref_num = (Replace(Replace(ultima_ref, "(", ""), ")", ""))








nova_linha_ref = CInt(ultima_ref_num) + 1

nova_ref = "'(" + CStr(nova_linha_ref) + ")"
Cells(prox_ref_linha, 1) = (nova_ref)



 
  
Cells(prox_ref_linha, 2) = ref

End If



Dim ultima_celula_find As Variant, Filename As String
Dim ultima_linha As Integer, ultima_coluna As Integer


Set ultima_celula_find = Cells.Find(What:="Página 2 de 2", _
                                  After:=Cells(1, 1), _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 MatchCase:=False)
                                 
ultima_linha = CInt(Split(ultima_celula_find.Address, "$")(2))



Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name + "-" + CStr(CInt(revisao_atual + 1))

ultima_coluna = CInt(20) 'T


 Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ultima_linha, ultima_coluna)).Select
 
 
'    Range("R1").Activate
   ' Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, PrToFileName:=Filename
    
    
    
    'Range("A1:T119").Select
Dim nome_plan_ativa As String, celula_nova_revisao As Variant, nova_revisao As Integer
    
 nome_plan_ativa = Split(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")(0)
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        caminho + "\PDF\" + nome_plan_ativa + " - " + CStr(CInt(revisao_atual + 1)) _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False


Worksheets("Revisões").Activate
Set celula_nova_revisao = Cells.Find(What:="", _
                                  After:=Cells(1, 1), _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                 MatchCase:=False)
nova_revisao = CInt(Split(celula_nova_revisao.Address, "$")(2))



Cells(nova_revisao, 1) = (revisao_atual) + 1
Cells(nova_revisao, 2) = atualizacao.TextBox5
Cells(nova_revisao, 3) = atualizacao.TextBox7
Cells(nova_revisao, 4) = atualizacao.TextBox8

Worksheets(nome_aba).Activate
Cells(2, 18) = (revisao_atual) + 1
Cells(3, 18) = atualizacao.TextBox5



End If


ActiveWorkbook.Save

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next k


ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets("PLANILHA REFERÊNCIA").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Os dados foram atualizados!", vbInformation, "Info"

If proximo = True Then
MsgBox "Selecione o próximo dado que deve ser alterado!", vbInformation, "Info"
dados_alterados.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells` indicates the `ActiveWorkbook`, you should specify which workbook you want to look in.

Comment: One line of code from a loop can surely not cut it. You need to add more detail and share more code to get some serious help.